# Is private getter allowed for apex:attribute assignTo?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

In essence, I tried the following setup. I throw an exception in my example because it is simpler to determine if the `setter` is being called.

**Component**

```
<apex:component controller="MyController">
    <apex:attribute name="recordId" assignTo="{!controllingId}" type="Id"
        required="true" description="Id to set" />
</apex:component>
```

**Controller**

```
public class MyController
{
    public class VFException extends Exception { }
    public Id controllingId
    {
        get;
        set { throw new VFException(); }
    }
}
```

The above results in a script-thrown exception, as expected. But if I remove the `getter` or make it `private`, the `setter` no longer gets called. Why?

```
public Id controllingId { set { throw new VFException(); } }
```

The above allows for a page load. Yet this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm) has examples where properties are write-only or have a private setter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While properties may be a combination of read-only, write-only, or read-write, the assignTo attribute will not work correctly without both a getter and setter. That's because assignTo is actually a two-way property. Most Visualforce expressions will only bind to an attribute that is both readable and writeable with at least public access.

This is covered in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_attribute.htm), which states:

> **assignTo**  A setter method that assigns the value of this
>   attribute to a class variable in the associated custom component
>   controller. If this attribute is used, getter and setter methods, or a
>   property with get and set values, must be defined.

Comment: Just realized it is in the `apex:attribute` [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_attribute.htm)...dumb mistake. If you merge in the description for `assignTo`, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @AdrianLarson It's amazing how often we miss stuff in the documentation. In fact, *I* didn't know this was in the documentation (I just knew it to be true).